# Pywin32 opening excel files in the Office's network

Tags: python-3.x, excel, pywin32, win32com, pathlib

I tried to open an excel file with pywin32 library, using the standard procedure, but i can't open when the file is the office's network:

```
import win32com.client as win32
import pathlib
'creating the PATH with a numeric adress'
path = pathlib.Path('//XX.XX.XX.XX/File1/SubFile1')
file = 'excel_file.xlsx'
PATH = path/file
'calling the excel and try to open the file'
excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Excel.Application")
'trying to open the file'
wb1 = excel.Workbook.Open(rf'{PATH}')
```

when I do execute this code raises this error in the console:

com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0,'Microsoft Excel','It was not possible to find (PATH). Is it possible that he was moved or renamed or excluded?', xlmain11.chm',0,-2146827284), None)

And the file is in the path. It has not been moved, or deleted or either renamed.